Infra Down time prediction using ML
I have to predict the Infra down time for tenants hosted in multiple pods. I use signals like Average Page time, Application/DB CPU times, UI and other errors from the infra at a max(5min grain) or sum for errors.
Typical patterns that we see during downtime are spikes, high volume of feature(sum of feature for x time) and high # of errors. I have used a Isolation forest to identify anomalies but, they were capturing local spikes too which are not very useful for us and any machine learning model must scale to multiple tenants which have signal range according to tenant size.
For the PoC I have used a simple method to use percentile value and IQR(10, 3) for thresholds and flagged them as anomalies, then I have used window function to calculate the no of anomalies within the window and set a threshold on the # anomalies to define if a downtime has occurred and used continues windows the downtime has been predicted to calculate the time of downtime.
Could you suggest any ML technics that can help solve this?
what other patterns I can look out for?
Any ML approach to help me automate this?
What other thresholding can I use?
Any research on this kind of work?
Thank you ML folks!!
